# Joint distribution of $X_1$ and $X_1 + X_2$

Tags: self-study

Given that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid $U(0,1)$ distributed random variables, what is the joint distribution of $X_1$ and $Y = X_1 + X_2$? I think it should be something like $f(x_1,y) = f(y|x_1)f(x_1)$, but what is $f(y|x1)$ given that $Y$ is triangular?

Comment: The joint distribution function of $(X_1,Y)$ is $P(X_1<x, Y<y) = P(X_1<x, X_1+X_2<y)$, based on the definition of $Y$. Now look at the last expression and try to spot something.